# is it possible to do multiple facebook messenger bot in singe node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I want 5 messenger bots and it should be running in one node server.Right now am using 5 different server for 5 messenger bots.how will i give logic so that i can differentiate that call is coming from this particular messenger.and send the callback to that respective messenger bot

```
app.get('/webhook', function (req, res) {
if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'I_Am_Special') {
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
    console.log("Inside Webhooks encountered")
}
res.send('Error, wrong token')
```

})

Comment: can you please share tutorial link?

Comment: Hi @deep i followed this link for understanding https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference and there is demo code in gihub also u can try that

Comment: Just use different callback URLs …?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Heroku Server. It allows you to create maximun of 5 applications. You also need to create 5 applications on your facebook developer's account which runs on 5 different facebook pages. So you can run 5 bots in a same server!

Comment: Dude am not asking for server host here i know that there is heroku and bluemix kind of servers are there.My question is how can i differentiate that am getting call from particular application bot if i am using same URL for all the 5 application .